# Suspended music does not resume upon dismissal of MPMoviePlayerViewController subclass

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I have created a subclass of MPMoviePlayerViewController in order to suspend any background audio that is playing (e. g. Pandora, Music app) while my video is playing back so that its own audio can be heard.  Upon completion of my video, I would like the suspended audio to resume playing.

I was able to get this working with the Apple-provided MoviePlayer sample code and the associated video (which is m4v format but has no audio).  However, when I used the video I need to playback (which is mp4 format and *does* have audio), it does not work, i. e. the suspended music does not resume when the video finishes.  Note that the MoviePlayer sample code uses an MPMoviePlayerController whereas I would prefer to use an MPMoviePlayerViewController if possible in order to get the behavior and controls I want for free.

When I use my MPMoviePlayerViewController subclass, the suspended audio doesn't resume after playback of either video.  I'll go to a MPMoviePlayerController if I have to, but only if I can figure out how to playback the needed video and resume music when it finishes!

Here's my MPMoviePlayerViewController subclass:

```
#import "SACMoviePlayerViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@implementation SACMoviePlayerViewController

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  if ([self isBeingPresented])
  {
    [self configureAudioSession];
  }
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
  if ([self isBeingDismissed])
  {
    [self deactivateAudioSession];
  }
  [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

-(void) configureAudioSession
{
  NSError *error = nil;
  BOOL configured = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:0 error:&error];
  NSLog(@"Audio session %@", configured ? @"configured" : @"not configured");
  if (error != nil)
  {
    NSLog(@"Configuration error is %@", [error localizedDescription]);
  }
}

-(void) deactivateAudioSession
{
  NSError *error = nil;
  BOOL deactivated = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO withOptions:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:&error];
  NSLog(@"Audio session %@", deactivated ? @"deactivated" : @"not deactivated");
  if (error != nil)
  {
    NSLog(@"Deactivation error is %@", [error localizedDescription]);
  }
}

@end
```

When I play the movie without audio using this view controller, I see the following in the log:

```
2014-02-10 10:48:48.065 PlayMovie[39385:60b] Audio session configured
2014-02-10 10:49:11.196 PlayMovie[39385:60b] Audio session deactivated
```

When I play the movie I need to play using this view controller, I see the following in the log:

```
2014-02-10 10:49:17.882 PlayMovie[39385:60b] Audio session configured
2014-02-10 10:50:16.023 PlayMovie[39385:60b] Audio session not deactivated
2014-02-10 10:50:16.033 PlayMovie[39385:60b] Deactivation error is The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 2003329396.)
```

This is consistent with what I've seen when I use an MPMoviePlayerController directly, but the audio resumes in the first case and not in the second (needed) case.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is not possible.  Seems like a bug if you ask me.  Oh well.

> Hello Michael,
>
> Thank you for contacting Apple Developer Technical Support (DTS). Our
>   engineers have reviewed your request and have concluded that there is
>   no supported way to achieve the desired functionality given the
>   currently shipping system configurations.
>
> If you would like for Apple to consider adding support for such
>   features in the future, please submit an enhancement request via the
>   Bug Reporter tool at http://bugreport.apple.com.
>
> While you were initially charged a technical support incident for this
>   support request, we have assigned a replacement incident back to your
>   account.
>
> Thank you for taking the time to file this report. We truly appreciate
>   your help in discovering and isolating issues.
>
> Best Regards,
>
> Developer Technical Support  Apple Worldwide Developer Relations